# Database design for storing Facebook likes of a user

Tags: mysql, sql, facebook

I'm getting all the likes of the current user, and storing them to a table (user_id, liked_id). The problem is, when I get all the likes again and if there is a change, I just want to insert the new likes. How can I do this efficiently since many users have lots of likes?

Comment: What database server (brand and version) are you using? Please retag your question appropriately to get more exact answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the (user_id, liked_id) the clustered, primary key of the table. Use a fill-factor of the index that makes room for new pairs and make sure that your update clauses can make efficient use of the clustered index (i.e. always include the user_id in the where clause).

Comment: Thanks, but will it work slow if I want to look for user_id's that liked something?

Comment: If you are doing a lookup on the beginning it will be able to use the index, e.g. `where user_id like 'abc%'`. If you are looking for it anywhere within the string, e.g. `where user_id like '%abc%'`, you will need a full table scan which is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make composite/ combined primary key or make combined of both field as unique.
So, it will not add the data that are already there due to key error.Hence only new data will be inserted.

Comment: That would lead the entire statement to be rolled back, loosing legitimate data as well.